# Difference between 몽골 and 몽고

Tags: word-choice, translation, place-names

The English edition of Wiktionary lists both as translations of [Mongolia](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Mongolia#Translations). The Korean edition of Wikipedia has something about [terminology](https://ko.wikipedia.org/wiki/%EB%AA%BD%EA%B3%A8#.EB.AA.85.EC.B9.AD), but it's a bit unclear with machine translation.

Naver doesn't explain the difference between the two: [몽고](http://endic.naver.com/krenEntry.nhn?sLn=en&entryId=e323c751cec047dbbbe85dc6cf94cf29&query=%EB%AA%BD%EA%B3%A0) versus [몽골](http://endic.naver.com/krenEntry.nhn?sLn=en&entryId=088a21bb4c264dc59073b911583c240a&query=%EB%AA%BD%EA%B3%A8).

What's the difference between the two?

Comment: somewhat related : https://korean.stackexchange.com/questions/1711/what-do-koreans-call-genghis-khan :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

몽골 is a transliteration into Hangul, but 몽고 (蒙古) comes from the Chinese characters for Mongolia. The latter is also a transliteration of sorts, but via Chinese.

The *National Institute of Korean Language's Korean-English Learners' Dictionary* entries explain the differences a little better. At least it mentions on the entry for [몽고](https://krdict.korean.go.kr/eng/dicSearch/SearchView?wordMatchFlag=N&mainSearchWord=Mongolia&currentPage=1&sort=W&searchType=W&proverbType=&exaType=&ParaWordNo=92055&nation=eng&nationCode=6&viewType=A&blockCount=10&viewTypes=on):

> the name is derived by reading "Mongolia" in Sino-Korean characters.

From my personal experience, 몽골 is the more common way to say it. The entry for [몽골](https://krdict.korean.go.kr/eng/dicSearch/SearchView?ParaWordNo=68750&nationCode=6&nation=eng&captchaNumber=&comment_user_name=&wordComment=&viewTypes=on&myViewWord=92055) also has 3 stars, meaning it's a very common word, whereas the entry for [몽고](https://krdict.korean.go.kr/eng/dicSearch/SearchView?wordMatchFlag=N&mainSearchWord=Mongolia&currentPage=1&sort=W&searchType=W&proverbType=&exaType=&ParaWordNo=92055&nation=eng&nationCode=6&viewType=A&blockCount=10&viewTypes=on) has none. According to the [Korean Wikipedia page on Mongolia](https://ko.wikipedia.org/wiki/%EB%AA%BD%EA%B3%A8) (headword spelled 몽골) and its [source](http://v.media.daum.net/v/20170516030257258) for this information written by a Mongolian person living in Korea, Korean people do in fact sometimes use 몽고, but Mongolians find it offensive because it harkens back to the time when China viewed them as the barbaric "Huns."

Comment: Wikipedia's entry on [Kotobagari](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kotobagari) (Japanese political correctness) notes that "蒙古" used to be used in Japanese, but isn't any more to avoid offense.

Comment: @AndrewGrimm Interesting, I wonder about Chinese now...